# CSS Animate using translate causes unwanted pixel shift

Tags: html, css, animation

Trying to create an animation where four sections intersect to create a circle. However, when the last section starts moving there is a weird pixel shift.

Tried using padding-bottom as the property and got the same result

Here is the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/52vu6e1f/1/

```
<body class="MW-Body">
    <div class="MW-ContentWrapper">
        <div class="Underlay small-12"></div>
        <div class="Overlay small-12">
            <div class="Circle-Container">
                <div class="Circle-Container-Inner clearfix">
                    <div class="Popup1 Popup1-Animation"></div>
                    <div class="Popup2 Popup2-Animation"></div>
                    <div class="Popup3 Popup3-Animation"></div>
                    <div class="Popup4 Popup4-Animation"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

html{font-size: 10px !important;}

body{
    min-width: 350px;
}
.Overlay{display: block}

div[class^="Popup"]{
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 15.625rem solid transparent;
    border-right: 15.625rem solid transparent; 
    border-bottom: 15.625rem solid black;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15.625rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15.625rem;
    transform-origin:top;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;

    display: block
}

.Circle-Container{}
.Circle-Container-Inner{position:relative;width:31.25rem;height:31.25rem;left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate( -50%, 0%);
    -moz-transform:   translate( -50%, 0%);
    -ms-transform:    translate( -50%, 0%);
    -o-transform:     translate( -50%, 0%);
    transform:        translate( -50%, 0%);
    display: inline-block;
}

.MW-ContentWrapper .Popup1{border-bottom: 15.625rem solid black;transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-200%, 0);}
.MW-ContentWrapper .Popup2{border-bottom: 15.625rem solid red;transform: rotate(180deg) translate(0, 200%);}
.MW-ContentWrapper .Popup3{border-bottom: 15.625rem solid yellow;transform: rotate(270deg) translate(200%, 0);}
.MW-ContentWrapper .Popup4{border-bottom: 15.625rem solid green;transform: rotate(360deg) translate(0, 300%);}

@keyframes SnapInTop {
  0% {
   transform:translate(0, -200%) rotate(180deg);

  }
  100% {
    transform:translate(0, 0)  rotate(180deg);

  }
}
@keyframes SnapInRight {
  0% {
   transform:translate(200%, 0) rotate(270deg);

  }
  100% {
    transform:translate(0, 0)  rotate(270deg);

  }
}
@keyframes SnapInBottom {
  0% {
   transform:translate(0, 200%) rotate(360deg);

  }
  100% {
    transform:translate(0, 0)  rotate(360deg);

  }
}
@keyframes SnapInLeft {
  0% {
   transform:translate(-200%, 0) rotate(90deg);

  }
  100% {
    transform:translate(0, 0)  rotate(90deg);

  }
}
.Popup1-Animation {
  animation-name: SnapInLeft;
  animation-duration: .5s; 
  animation-timing-function: linear; 
  animation-delay: 0;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-play-state: running; 
}
.Popup2-Animation {
  animation-name: SnapInTop;
  animation-duration: .5s; 
  animation-timing-function: linear; 
  animation-delay: .5s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-play-state: running; 
}
.Popup3-Animation {
  animation-name: SnapInRight;
  animation-duration: .5s; 
  animation-timing-function: linear; 
  animation-delay: 1s;

  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-play-state: running; 
}
.Popup4-Animation {
  animation-name: SnapInBottom;
  animation-duration: .5s; 
  animation-timing-function: linear; 
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-play-state: running; 
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em){
    html{font-size:10px !important;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em){
    html{font-size:12px !important;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 90.063em){
    html{font-size:14px !important;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 120.063em){
    html{font-size:16px !important;}
}
```

Comment: What is the "weird pixel shift"? What browsers does it happen in?

Comment: What do you mean "a weird pixel shift"? I don't get it. The only thing that shifts during the last section is the whole graph, and that is because the scroll bar disappears, so the position of the graph shifts. Just hide the scroll bar as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of the overflow of the content. Use this

```
.Circle-Container{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/52vu6e1f/4/).

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing this line :

```
.Circle-Container-Inner{position:relative;width:31.25rem;height:31.25rem;left: 50%;
```

to this :

```
.Circle-Container-Inner{position:fixed;width:31.25rem;height:31.25rem;left: 50%;
```

making position fixed. so you can add the whole thing to another container with your required position EDIT  :e.g adding relative position to Circe-Container class